# MYSQL GROUP BY not showing correct date

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have run into a small problem with the `GROUP BY` function in MYSQL v. 5.7.15-log.

```
SELECT ca.CategoryID, ca.CategoryName, ca.CategoryDescription, co.Commenter, co.CommentDate 
FROM forum_category AS ca 
JOIN forum_comment AS co 
    ON co.CategoryID = ca.CategoryID
ORDER BY ca.CategoryID ASC, co.CommentDate DESC
```

resulting in

```
CategoryID  CategoryName    CategoryDescription Commenter   CommentDate
1           Admin           test1               Pino        "2017-04-16 15:47:41"
1           Admin           test1               Pino        "2017-04-16 15:36:40"
1           Admin           test1               Pino        "2017-04-16 15:25:30"
2           test            bla                 Pino        "2017-04-16 17:17:56"
2           test            bla                 Pino        "2017-04-16 17:17:21"
2           test            bla                 Pino        "2017-04-16 15:56:16"
```

Where what i want is

```
CategoryID  CategoryName    CategoryDescription Commenter   CommentDate
1           Admin           test1               Pino        "2017-04-16 15:47:41"
2           test            bla                 Pino        "2017-04-16 17:17:56"
```

I have tried a few different thing, but no luck so far.

I did read in here to try

```
SELECT a.CategoryID, CategoryName, CategoryDescription, Commenter, CommentDate FROM (
    SELECT ca.CategoryID, ca.CategoryName, ca.CategoryDescription, co.Commenter, co.CommentDate 
    FROM forum_category AS ca 
    JOIN forum_comment AS co 
        ON co.CategoryID = ca.CategoryID
    ORDER BY ca.CategoryID ASC, co.CommentDate DESC
) AS a
ORDER BY a.CategoryID
```

but that only resulted in the wrong date as well

```
CategoryID  CategoryName    CategoryDescription Commenter   CommentDate
1           Admin           test1               Pino        "2017-04-16 15:25:30"
2           test            bla                 Pino        "2017-04-16 15:56:16"
```

Thanks in advance to the MYSQL Ninjas out there

Comment: Which date do you want it to output? Min date or max?

Comment: The max date/latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ca.CategoryID, ca.CategoryName, ca.CategoryDescription, co.Commenter, MAX(co.CommentDate) as max_date
FROM forum_category AS ca 
JOIN forum_comment AS co ON co.CategoryID = ca.CategoryID
GROUP BY ca.CategoryID, ca.CategoryName, ca.CategoryDescription, co.Commenter
ORDER BY ca.CategoryID ASC, max_date DESC;
```